# parse json timespan to time value

Tags: objective-c, json, xcode

I know how to parse JSON datetime to `NSDate`, now I get timespan value from JSON like

```
dEndTime = PT13H;
dStartTime = PT8H30M;
```

How can I parse this?

I need an output like this

```
dStartTime = "08:30 AM"
dEndTime = "01:00 PM"
```

Can anyone help me for this.

Comment: What kind of format is that?

Comment: Well you have a problem. Your two dates are not in same format. dStartTime is `@"vHH'H'mm'M'"` and dEndTime is `@"vHH'H'"`. Conditional formatting seems like overkill, can you sort out your JSON response to have them both in the same format?